# PyQT5/QTDesigner - I'm getting a "This file contains top level spacers" error when there are no spacers and I have layouts

Tags: python, layout, pyqt5, qt-designer

[image: Screenshot of the error with object elements in view.]

The error displays even when there are no spacers in the design. The object class viewer is on the left for reference, but there are no spacers in the file.

I used a spacer previously but removed it. However, I'm still getting this error, even when I have added layouts to the main window/central widget.

Comment: That error also happens when trying to use spacers in *child* containers that have no layout set. Please provide the UI file or at least a screenshot of the full, expanded object inspector.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I closed and re-opened QTDesigner, the file seemed to work normally again. Most likely just the IDE messing up after being open a while.